# Primes representable by either $x^2+36y^2$ or $4x^2+9y^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, quadratic-forms

Is there a simple criterion for primes that are representable by either $x^2 + 36 y^2$  or $4x^2 + 9y^2$?

This is not my area of expertise, so any pointers appreciated.

I had a look in the Cox book *"Primes of the form $x^2 + n y^2$"*, but if those specific forms are there, I missed it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The question might be asking about primes for which either representation applies. In that case, $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$   there is an expression $u^2 + 36 v^2 = p$    precisely when $x^4 + 3$  factors into four linear factors $\pmod p,$   that is four distinct roots. Let me check whether it is enough to have one root.  This is from [Kenneth S. Williams and D. Liu, Tamkang Journal of Mathematics, volume 25, number 4, Winter 1994;  pages 321-334.](https://journals.math.tku.edu.tw/index.php/TKJM/article/view/4461)

Once $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12},$   it is enough to have one root of $x^4 + 3 \pmod p$

Meanwhile, this can probably be done with biquadratic reciprocity, as in Ireland and Rosen.

More description:  we need only primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12}$ Now,    we can **always find** a number $a$  such that $$  (x^2 + a) ( x^2 - a) \equiv x^4 + 3  \pmod p$$
Indeed, we demanded $(-3|p) = 1,$  we are taking $a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$

**If   $a$ is not a square** $\pmod p$    then $p = 4 u^2 + 9 v^2 $  In this case the two quadratics displayed are irreducible $\pmod p.$

**If we can take $a = b^2, $**  so that
$$   (x^2 + b^2) ( x^2 - b^2) \equiv x^4 + 3  \pmod p$$
then $ p = u^2 + 36 v^2 .$  Note how we can see the condition $b^4 \equiv -3 \pmod p$
Let's see,  $( -1 | p) + 1,$ there is an $i$  with $i^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p,$   we may define $c = bi$  and write
$$   (x^2 -c^2) ( x^2 - b^2) \equiv x^4 + 3  \pmod p$$  to display the four roots

Comment: For $\,x^2+36y^2\,$ it is [A107142](https://oeis.org/A107142) and for $\,4x^2+9y^2\,$ it is [A107141](https://oeis.org/A107141).